# Do events affect exit rate? (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics

I know that firing an event affects bounce rate of the page (when fired, page won't be counted as bounce).

What I wasn't able to find an answer is that if events affect the exit rate as well. Meaning, if you have a page that you fire an event on, will that page have lower exit rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an exit simply means there wasn't another pageview in the same session. Events (or other hit types) are not considered with exits or exit percentages.

Comment: While I totally agree with you I wonder if you have actually tested this somehow or if you just go by the definition of "exit rate" :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would be nice to have a reference to point to.

Comment: @hakunin this was the best I could find: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2525491?hl=en, though it doesn't mention events in particular.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I have a site that sends timing hits and event hits on nearly 100% of pages, and some of my pages still have high % Exits, so in that sense, yes, I've tested it.